# Search function with editText - ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, search, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in android, with my ListBooks I retrieve all books from my FirebaseDatabase and I see it very clearly but when I use the search function my List is not correct. I don't know why. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

**ListBooks:**

```
    public class ListBooks extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText searchBooks;
    Context mContext;
    static final String KEY = "KEY", TAG_LOGIN = "TAG_LOGIN";
    String key, getTagLogin;

    String user_name, searchSth;
    DatabaseReference user;
    DatabaseReference userBook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books").child("User's books");
    ListView mListView;
    ArrayList<String> mArrayUserName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mArrayTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mArrayAuthor = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mArrayPrice = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mArrayImage = new ArrayList<>();
    customAdapter customAdapter;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_books);
        mContext = this;



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        getTagLogin = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_LOGIN);



        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        customAdapter = new customAdapter(mContext, mArrayTitle, mArrayAuthor, mArrayUserName, mArrayPrice, mArrayImage);
        mListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        userBook.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                UserBook userBook = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserBook.class);
                user_name = userBook.user_name;
                String book_title = userBook.book_title;
                String book_author = userBook.book_author;
                String book_price = userBook.book_price;
                String book_cover = userBook.book_urlImage;


                mArrayUserName.add(user_name);
                mArrayTitle.add(book_title);
                mArrayAuthor.add(book_author);
                mArrayPrice.add(book_price);
                mArrayImage.add(book_cover);
                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        searchBooks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_books);

        searchBooks.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                customAdapter.clear();
                searchSth = searchBooks.getText().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                userBook.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            UserBook userBook = snapshot.getValue(UserBook.class);
                            String book_title = userBook.book_title;
                            if (book_title.contains(searchSth) && searchSth != null){
                                user_name = userBook.user_name;
                                String book_author = userBook.book_author;
                                String book_price = userBook.book_price;
                                String book_cover = userBook.book_urlImage;


                                mArrayUserName.add(user_name);
                                mArrayTitle.add(book_title);
                                mArrayAuthor.add(book_author);
                                mArrayPrice.add(book_price);
                                mArrayImage.add(book_cover);
                                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });




    }

}
```

**customAdapter.java:**

```
    public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> user_name;
    ArrayList<String> book_title;
    ArrayList<String> book_author;
    ArrayList<String> book_price;
    ArrayList<String> book_cover;


    public customAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> user_name, ArrayList<String> book_title,
                         ArrayList<String> book_author, ArrayList<String> book_price, ArrayList<String> book_cover) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_list_books, book_title);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.mContext = context;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.book_title = book_title;
        this.book_author = book_author;
        this.book_price = book_price;
        this.book_cover = book_cover;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_books, null, true);

        TextView user = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_search);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
        TextView author = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
        TextView price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceBook);
        ImageView bookImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.coverBookSearch);


            user.setText(user_name.get(position));
            title.setText(book_title.get(position));
            author.setText(book_author.get(position));
            price.setText(book_price.get(position));
            if (book_cover.get(position).startsWith("https://")) {
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(book_cover.get(position)).into(bookImage);
            } else {
                bookImage.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(book_cover.get(position)));
            }


        return rowView;

    }





    //Transform a String in a Bitmap Image (used with camera)
    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try {
            byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserBook:**

```
public class UserBook {

    public String user_key;
    public String user_tag_login;
    public String book_title;
    public String book_author;
    public String book_urlImage;
    public String book_publisher;
    public String book_price;
    public String user_name;

    public UserBook() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public UserBook(String user_name, String user_key, String user_tag_login, String book_title, String book_author, String book_urlImage,  String book_publisher, String book_price) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.user_key = user_key;
        this.user_tag_login = user_tag_login;
        this.book_title = book_title;
        this.book_author = book_author;
        this.book_urlImage = book_urlImage;
        this.book_publisher = book_publisher;
        this.book_price = book_price;
    }


}
```

Comment: Make a Book class object to hold all those strings. Don't throw a bunch of separate arraylists of strings together.

Comment: i have a book object. I update that object in my question. But how i put an object in my list view?

Comment: Make a `BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserBook>` that stores one `ArrayList<UserBook>`.

Comment: Problem SOLVED.... thanks you very much, if you want write an answer I'll vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guarantees that this will fix the searching problem, but it certainly reduces the complexity of the code.

Replace all these

```
ArrayList<String> user_name;
ArrayList<String> book_title;
ArrayList<String> book_author;
ArrayList<String> book_price;
ArrayList<String> book_cover;
```

With one of these

```
ArrayList<UserBook> books;
```

Then

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserBook>
```

And change out all the other logic for displaying the book object in the adapter.